# Не могу отключить проверку ключей

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Мне нужно сделать синхронизацию 2 баз данных MySQL. В этих базах есть внешние ключи, поэтому при синхронизации возникают ошибки.

Я решил отключить проверку. Но она не отключается. Делаю вот такую команду:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0
```

После этого проверяю:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks'
```

Получаю 1 (ON). Почему не можно отключить такую проверку?

Кстати, использую Yii2, пишу консольную команду

Comment: а прав юзеру хватает?

Comment: ошибки не получаю

Comment: тут пишут что для innodb отключить не получится https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql

Comment: там же есть вариант c alter table, но тут короче 3 варианта https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-temporarily-disable-foreign-key-constraints.html